# Webview loading youtube difficulty

Tags: android, html, iframe, webview

I got a webview and in it i load Html. The problem is that when it loads , it looks tiny and doesn't fit normally in screen. Can any1 suggest me a solution for this problem ??

myClass.class

```
 mWebViewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            });
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            mWebView.canGoBack();



            final String html = "\n" +
                    "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                    "<html>\n" +
                    "   <head>\n" +
                    "   <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0\">\n" +
                    "       <title>Interface\t</title>\n" +
                    "   </head>\n" +
                    "   <body>" +
                    myIframeRecieved
                    + "   </body></html>";

            //     mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Select.from(VideoResource.class).where(Condition.prop("article_identifier").eq(selectedArticle.getArticleIdentifier())).first().getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    view.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
                    return true;


                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                }

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                }
            });
```

myIframeRecieved looks like :

```
<iframe frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/AOr4zw59A34?rel=0'></iframe><div class='caption'></div><div class='copyright'></div><div class='clear'></div>
```

myIframeRecieved i can't modify,because i receive it from server

Now when im done loading in webview it looks like [this link](http://postimg.org/image/9bdcowfaf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `width='100%' height='100%'` to the `<iframe>` tag, and see if this changes the layout.

Another option to try, is to substring the url from the string and pass it to the WebView;

Something like this:

```
String url = extractUrlFrom(myIframeRecieved); // you implement this
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```